# Optional Input Context in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a voice commands such as

```
- turn on lights in the lounge
- turn on lights in the kitchen
```

The room (lounge, kitchen) and is a mandatory parameter is stored as a context variable.

My question is - is there a way to have an optional input context for an intent. If context exists, use data from it, otherwise get the user to specify the context via slot filling.

Without this feature, it seems I need to have two intents which are almost identical.

```
- TurnOnLights_WithContext
- TurnOnLights_WithoutContext
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, so I want to make sure I understand - you're setting "lounge" in a context before the Intent where they say "turn on the lights"? Or you want to be able to handle "Turn on the lights in the lounge" "Also turn on the tv" (with the implication that it be in the lounge). If you can show screen shots of the Intents, that would be helpful.

Comment: @Prisoner - it was the latter. I figured out the solution, answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to set the default value for the parameter from the context. If the value exists in the context it will be set. If not, the user will have to specify the value via slot-filling.

See screenshots below

[image]

[image]

Comment: This addresses the issue of setting a parameter, but I find that it runs into a higher level problem because Dialogflow won't call intents unless the input context is present. No matter how high a priority I give to an intent, if there is a missing context, it won't be invoked.

Comment: @MarkLewis I'm also facing the same problem. Were you able to find a solution to this?